# Using regex to edit a index.html file using a batch script

Tags: html, regex, bash

Hi is it possible to edit a .html file using regex contained inside a bash scrip?

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
replaceText="<a href="some-file-here" id="text">link to the new file</a>"

#open index.html file stream(how?)

#do some if condition that meets the regex below:
IF index.html contains <td abbr="fileOne">(.*)</td>
Index.html replaceText
```

I'm quite new to bash scripting but I was wondering if the above is possible?

This has to work on both osx unix and linux.

Here is the index.html example:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="width: 50%; height: 50%;">
<div style="top: 10%; left: 10%; position: absolute;">
<img border="0" src=“icon.png” alt="Hello World" width="120" height="120">
<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
<td abbr=“file one”><a href=“someFile” id="text">Install file one here…</a></td>
<td abbr=“fileTwo”><a href=“someFileTwo” id="text">install file Two here…</a></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

edit: i tried using sed command be

```
sed -i.bak 's/<td abbr="fileOne">(.*?)<\/td>/WHAT_YOU_WANT/' index.html
```

however i get the above error when i open the .bak file:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

Comment: do you mean batch scripting or bash scripting? you said that you wanted your solution to work on osx unix and linux but batch-files are windows only?

Comment: Sorry bash scripting. has to work on unix/linux

Comment: use sed, POSIX compliant sed is available on all those systems, see answer. (that is provided you want to replace the line matched with your replace_text which is what the question seems to be asking)

Comment: i tried using sed but it complains about the html containing newlines. When i tried to manually remove and inline the while html, it then starts complaining about the "<" characters

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` command to do this.

If you want to replace `<td abbr="fileOne">(.*)</td>` you can use the following:

```
sed 's/<td abbr=[“"]fileOne["”]>(.*?)<\/td>/WHAT_YOU_WANT/'
```

Here you have a working example:

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/eQ2yI0/2)**

You need to pass the `-i` option to `sed` to make the changes inline and create a backup of the original file before it does the changes in-place:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/<td abbr=["”]fileOne["”]>(.*?)<\/td>/WHAT_YOU_WANT/' index.html
```

If you don't want to use slashes as separator you can change it to `#` (and you don't have to skip slashes too using #):

```
sed -i.bak -E 's#<td abbr=["”]fileTwo["”]>(.*)?</td>#WHAT_YOU_WANT#' index.html
```

Comment: Cheers, how does sed open and interact with the index.html file?

Comment: sed 's/<td abbr="fileOne">(.*?)<\/td>/WHAT_YOU_WANT/' index.html > index.html

Comment: Hi i tried that example and it just wiped the contents of index.html

Comment: @jonney check again pls

Comment: Just did. it totaly removed the contents of the html file :( umm

Comment: edit: i just saw your update with the new optional arguments. trying now

Comment: ok i looked at the .bak file and saw this error: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: @jonney the .bak file is the backup you have to check the original file. Btw, if you have a sintax error you should have a typo. That works for me

Comment: @jonney try a simple execution like: sed -i.bak 's/<head>/WHAT_YOU_WANT/' index.html

Comment: @jonney, I'm sorry if cause any inconvenience. -i.bak works pretty well for me.

Comment: the simple command of editing the <head> works but not whats inside the td tag

Comment: @jonney I suspect of your sed version. So, try adding -E. 
Like: -E 's/<td abbr="fileOne">(.*?)<\/td>/WHAT_YOU_WANT/'

Comment: Nope. i got this following error: sed: 1: "s/<td abbr="FileOne">(. ...": RE error:sed: illegal option -- .
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

Comment: @jonney I've updated the answer with another expression. Both of them are working for me and also for other guys that posted comment. Check the updated answer and if it doesn't work post a comment with your execution, I think you have a typo.

Comment: @Fede did you notice the double quotes in the input?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Hi Avi... didn't see that. Thanks. I'll fix it right now

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if a certain pattern is available in a file and then run some other script if that is the case you could test the output of grep, I'm including this answer for completeness' sake.

```
if [ $(grep -c '<td abbr="fileOne">(.*?)<\/td>' index.html) -ne 0 ]
then
        some_func_you_want_to_run    #this is the case where the line is present
else
        exit 1                       #this is the case where it isn't
fi

exit 0
```

It bears noting that [regex's are not a good fix for parsing html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) but since I'm hoping all you are doing is replacing a single line then using sed as above would be the best way to do it. If you did have more stringent needs I'd recommend using a scripting language such as ruby, python or perl and an html parser such as nokogiri for ruby.